# Power BI: Customize X-axis labels from related table

Tags: powerbi

I have a column chart which plots data from Table A. Table A has release names and counts of defects in each release. Here is how it looks

[image: Column Chart]

I have another Table B which has the release dates. Schema of that table is:

```
Release_Name    Release_Date    Full_Release_Name
```

*Full_Release_Name* actually does not exist. I can create it as a calculated column which concatenates Release_Name and Release_Date.

In the column chart I want the X-axis labels to appear as e.g. **IR 18.4 19/12/2017**.

How can I do it, without adding a redundant concatenated column in Table A? I want to avoid this as the number of rows in Table A is going to be very large.

Answer (score 1):

I could resolve the issue as below.

1. Create a relation between the 2 tables
2. Add the Release_Date field from Table B as 2nd entry on Axis
3. Drilldown to level where it shows concatenated Release name and date.

If you spot a problem with this approach, let me know.